# Conditional log level on a statement in python?

Tags: python, logging

Is there a way to dynamically set which log level I want a statement logged as?

I have this code:

```
logging.info("Data Set Size => {0}".format(len(data)))
logging.info("Training Set Size => {0}".format(len(train)))
logging.info("Test Set Size => {0}".format(len(test)))
logging.info("Entire data set allocated => {0}".format(len(data) == len(train) + len(test)))
```

It very nicely outputs something similar to this, depending on the format I've set:

```
root        : INFO     Data Set Size => 10000
root        : INFO     Training Set Size => 7500
root        : INFO     Test Set Size => 2500
root        : INFO     Entire data set allocated => True
```

Now, the question I have, if the logic check in that last line is `False`, can I set that level to a `.warning`?

I could do something like this:

```
if len(data) == len(train) + len(test):
    logging.info("Entire data set allocated => {0}".format(True)
else:
    logging.warning("Entire data set allocated => {0}".format(False)
```

But, is there a way to do it in fewer lines?

Comment: Use %s style formatting with loggers, passing values as arguments.  This is because the logging module supports it, strings wont be formatted unless the msg is emitted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Logger.log()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.log) instead of the functions named after levels; this takes a level as the first argument:

```
entire_set = len(data) == len(train) + len(test)
logging.log(logging.WARNING if entire_set else logging.INFO,
            "Entire data set allocated => {0}".format(entire_set))
```

The `logging.warning()` and `logging.info()` functions are merely shortcuts for calling `logging.log()` with a given log level.

You probably want to switch to using a dedicated `Logger` object rather than use the module-level functions; it'll allow you to configure logging more granularly and track where log messages came from by their logger name.

Comment: Since `warning` and `info` are shortcuts, that means I can keep those statements in place for the first three lines I'm logging and just modify the last line, correct? I don't need to switch everything to use `logging.log()`?

Comment: Right, but you have just put the conditional statement in one line :-) And you could also remove the `.format(False)`.

Comment: @NewGuy: yes, use the shortcuts where you can, use `logging.log()` when you need to use a dynamic level.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a conditional switch. Meaning: you need an if/else clause. With an if/else clause being required, there is no way to make it "shorter" than you have it. The only way to make this significantly shorter is that you come up with an approach that does not need to distinguish two cases.

And then I need to ask: why would you want to have this in shorter code? The code you propose is perfectly readable.

In your current proposal, you should remove the `.format(True)` and `.format(False)` fragments (the result is constant and known, so you can hardcode it). That however does not really shorten your code.

Answer (score -1):

If you want all following info loggings into warning loggings you could replace the info function by the warning function as shown:

```
if len(data) == len(train) + len(test):
    pass
else:
    logging.info = logging.warning
```

So you don't need to do this test when with every followed logging.info statement. If this is useful for you depends on the rest of the logging code of course.

I don't quite understand why you want to increase the logging level of a statement. Usually one does the reverse. If one critical condition fails one increases the loglevel with

```
logging.setLevel
```

and all logging statements with no info level have the warning level. Since the info statements are included in the logging, there is usually no need of increasing the level of the statement itself.

Comment: Don't use `if ...: pass`, `else:` when you can use `if len(data) != len(train) + len(test)` instead. Altering the method binding is a *terrible* idea however.

Comment: I don't want to change all future info messages to warnings, just the single statement.

Comment: `If :pass` was just along the lines of his statements. There is no need fo downvoting this. But since this is SO.... anyways, method binding can be very useful, this heavily depends on his code.

Comment: Not in this case; at best I'd use `log = logging.info` or `log = logging.warning` to store this as a local variable.